# Spring cloud config - override profile locally failed

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-client

I have a *microservice spring boot* with *spring cloud config client* configured.
I have 2 file:

```
application.properties
application-local.properties
```

When I start app with `./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local` my expectation was property loaded in `application-local.properties` was used to connect cloud config server, while I see in the log the property of `application.properties`.

[Startup logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9bFU.png)